# Convert MySQL query to Postgres 9.6 - issue with conditions and assignments

Tags: mysql, postgresql, tree-traversal

I am migrating one project, which has traversal tree integrated and was originally written above MySQL database.

Query below is used for moving nodes in the three and was working fine in MySQL. Exactly I have two testing nodes in tree, both in root level (0 depth) and moving second element to become child of first element.

Now I need to run it on PostgreSQL 9.6 and I am having troubles to convert following query:

```
UPDATE treeitems
SET
    depth = depth + IF(@subtree := lft >= 3 AND rgt <= 4, ( 1 - 0 ) , 0),
    lft = lft + IF(@subtree, -1, IF(lft >= 2, 2, 0)),
    rgt = rgt + IF(@subtree, -1, IF(rgt <= 4, 2, 0))
WHERE
    rgt >= 2
    AND
    lft <= 4
```

I was able to convert into something like this, but it did not solve error with assignment (@subtree :=):

```
UPDATE treeitems
SET
    depth = depth + @subtree := (CASE WHEN lft >= 3 AND rgt <= 4 THEN ( 1 - 0 ) 
ELSE 0 END),
    lft = lft + CASE WHEN @subtree THEN -1 ELSE (CASE WHEN lft >= 2 THEN 2 ELSE 
0 END) END,
    rgt = rgt + CASE WHEN @subtree THEN -1 ELSE (CASE WHEN rgt <= 4 THEN 2 ELSE 
0 END)END
WHERE
    rgt >= 2
    AND
    lft <= 4
```

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't support in query user vars like MySQL does.  But you should share the CREATE tabel statements for both database systems and the INSERT statements also for both database systems

Comment: You're gonna need to try and get your head around recursive CTEs for dealing with a tree structure in Postgres. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/queries-with.html

Comment: HI, thank you for your input, could you be more specific please? I am not sure exactly what approach follow using CTEs :(